# Чтение/запись в Эксель "xlsx" в рамках xml/zip

Tags: c++, excel

Подскажите пожалуйста по записи и чтению данных из ексель формата xlsx:

1)Файл ексель формата xlsx представляет собой набор файлов формата xml, как то спрятанных за формат xlsx, в этом легко убедится, если изменить расширение xlsx на zip и открыть его.

2)И собственно вопрос, как средствами с++ получить доступ на считывание данных с этого/этих xlm файлов ? То есть xlsx файл каким то образом нужно открыть в виде zip архива, прочитать его содержимое, выбрать нужный xml файл и читать оттуда данные.(вопрос парсинга самих считываемых данных не стоит).

3)И обратный вопрос как записать или изменить строку в нужном xml файле находящегося внутри xlsx-zip формата ?

Comment: Для работы с xlsx есть куча готовых библиотек, бери да пользуйся. Например, вот https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX

Comment: zed, сначала я так и сделал, только брал XLNT, но в итоге оказалось, что к примеру XLNT при загрузке файла от 12 Мб кидаеn эксепшн bad allocation, то есть XLNT при загрузке 12 Мб ексель файла занимает память более 2Гб(плюс у библиотеки полно других косяков). Ну че это такое ? :)  Так как на данный момент мне нужно Только читать просто данные из ячеек ексель, из ексель файлов большого размера я подумал реализовать свой метод, думаю такая узкая задача теоретически не должна быть прям очень сложной ?

Comment: вы посмотрели структуру файла - там некоторые xml просто необходимо вгрузить в память в виде таблицы - через них расшифровываются знаяения в ячейках

Comment: splash58, но не 2 же Гигабайта на 12 Мб файла ?? Вы когда 12 Мб ексель открываете в самом екселе - он что 2 Гб занимает в оперативке ? Если все xml файлы извлечь из архива получается 134 Мб, но ни как не 2 Гб. Это явный косяк библиотеки.

Comment: С первой либой не получилось, возьмите другую. И откройте issue для первой, чтобы автор мог её улучшить, если она ещё не заброшена. Это будет всяко быстрее, чем самому разбираться с форматом экселя и писать свой велосипед.

Comment: zed, если в итоге потребуется что то большее, чем просто чтение, то придётся без сомнений взять, но реализовать просто чтение - думается вполне возможно попробывать самому. Кто бы только подсказал с чего начать. А сами issue правятся очень медленно и походу с неохотой, так что рассчитывать на чужую библиотеку не очень хочется.

Comment: Попробовать можно, но мне думается, что это не так-то просто, как вам думается.

Comment: zed, Вы подскажите с чего начать ? :)  А там я отпишусь насколько сложно получилось :)

Comment: Можете начать отсюда: http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php

Comment: И ещё, а сколько в вашем файле строчек и колонок? OpenXLSX может открывать очень большие файлы (в миллион строк): https://github.com/troldal/OpenXLSX#memory-usage

Comment: zed, в среднем 450 тыщ. строк в 5 колонок.

Comment: Ага, ну вот и ответ, почему оно может не вмещаться в 2Гб, учитывая что повсеместно используется DOM-парсер xml. В таком случае вам либо надо писать свой велосипед с SAX парсером, либо добавить памяти и билдить 64-х битное приложение на готовых либах.

Comment: zed, да Вы правы, на 64-битах ошибки нет, но это не вариант. Поэтому и хотел попробовать свое сделать. Как я нагуглил, сам xlsx архив для доступа к xml - можно попробовать получить с помощью zlib.